# Making a PowerShell Graph Script faster

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I have the below PowerShell Graph script that pulls user details from an Azure AD.

I only have about 255 accounts and it takes about 2 min to run. I am betting this can be faster and I am doing something that is causing a performance hit.

Any ideas?

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Users
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Identity.SignIns
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Authentication

Select-MgProfile beta

Connect-MgGraph -Scopes User.Read.All,Organization.Read.All, AuditLog.Read.All,UserAuthenticationMethod.Read.All

$Output = Get-MgUser -CountVariable userCount -ConsistencyLevel eventual -All -Filter "UserType ne 'Guest'" | Select-Object ID, createdDateTime,displayName,userPrincipalName, LastPasswordChangeDateTime,OnPremisesDistinguishedName -ExpandProperty SignInActivity | Select-Object ID,userPrincipalName,displayName, createdDateTime, LastSignInDateTime,LastPasswordChangeDateTime,@{name='AuthMethod';expression={ ((Get-MgUserAuthenticationMicrosoftAuthenticatorMethod -all -UserId $_.ID ).devicetag) -join ',' } },@{name='AuthClientApp';expression={ ((Get-MgUserAuthenticationMicrosoftAuthenticatorMethod -all -UserId $_.ID | select -ExpandProperty AdditionalProperties).clientAppName) -join ',' } }, OnPremisesDistinguishedName

$Output
```

Comment: You can start with not using 3 `Select-Object`'s.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Abraham Zinala,; when you say not to use Select-Objects, what would you use in their place to get the same output?

Comment: you use just one.

Comment: you should get the most performance gain if you can batch the Get-MgUserAuthenticationMicrosoftAuthenticatorMethod at the moment these are going to be a single sequential request per user. There is no easy way of using batching in the powershell sdk https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell/issues/116 yet so you need to break the logic out from that oneliner. Keep in mind https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling-limits